# Reverse elements via pipeline

Tags: arrays, powershell, reverse

Is there a function that reverses elements passed via pipeline?

E.g.:

```
PS C:\> 10, 20, 30 | Reverse
30
20
10
```

Comment: As a pipleline only handles one object at a time you need to reverse the array before sending it to the pipe.

Answer (score 25):

You can cast $input within the function directly to a array, and then reverse that:

```
function reverse
{ 
 $arr = @($input)
 [array]::reverse($arr)
 $arr
}
```

Answer (score 10):

```
10, 20, 30 | Sort-Object -Descending {(++$script:i)}
```

Comment: Hello, Please add some code explanation to help user to figure out easily

Comment: "script" is the scope of the "i" variable which is incremented each time it is evaluated: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_scopes?view=powershell-7

Comment: a shorter version would be: 

10, 20, 30 | Sort-Object {(--$script:i)}

Comment: This only works if the input is sorted in ascending order

Comment: That is not reversing the original order...

Answer (score 6):

Here's a remarkably compact solution:

```
function Reverse
{
    [System.Collections.Stack]::new(@($input))
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's one approach:

```
function Reverse ()
{
    $arr = $input | ForEach-Object { $_ }
    [array]::Reverse($arr)
    return $arr
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Using $input works for pipe, but not for parameter.  Try this:

```
function Get-ReverseArray {
    Param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, Position = 0, ValueFromPipeLine = $true)]
        $Array
    )
    begin{
        $build = @()
    }
    process{
        $build += @($Array)
    }
    end{
        [array]::reverse($build)
        $build
    }
}
#set alias to use non-standard verb, not required.. just looks nicer
New-Alias -Name Reverse-Array -Value Get-ReverseArray
```

Test:

```
$a = "quick","brown","fox"

#--- these all work 
$a | Reverse-Array
Reverse-Array -Array $a
Reverse-Array $a

#--- Output for each
fox
brown
quick
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$array = 10,20,30; (($array.Length - 1)..0) | %{ $array[$_] }
```

Answer (score 1):

I realize this doesn't use a pipe, but I found this easier if you just wanted to do this inline, there is a simple way. Just put your values into an array and call the existing Reverse function like this:

```
$list = 30,20,10
[array]::Reverse($list)
# print the output.
$list
```

Put that in a PowerShell ISE window and run it the output will be 10, 20, 30.

Again, this is if you just want to do it inline. There is a function that will work for you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Linq.Enumerable.Reverse`, but it's hard work. Either of the following work:

```
,(10, 20, 30) | % { [Linq.Enumerable]::Reverse([int[]]$_) }
,([int[]]10, 20, 30) | % { [Linq.Enumerable]::Reverse($_) }
```

The two challenges are putting the whole array into the pipeline rather than one element at a time (solved by making it an array of arrays with the initial comma) and hitting the type signature of Reverse (solved by the `[int[]]`).

Answer (score 1):

One-liners inspired by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72567509):

```
[Collections.Stack]$array | Write-Verbose -vb

$array -as 'Collections.Stack' | Write-Verbose -vb

$array | &{ [Collections.Stack]@($Input) } | Write-Verbose -vb

$array | &{ @($Input) -as 'Collections.Stack' } | Write-Verbose -vb
```

The first one is the shortest, the second one looks the nicest, and the last two are for performing the reversal mid-pipeline rather than before the pipeline.

Answer (score -4):

Try:

```
10, 20, 30 | Sort-Object -Descending
```

Comment: This works if you also want to sort at the same time, but if you don't want to sort, this won't work. (E.g, maybe your original array was `20,10,30` and you want `30,10,20`)